# Quasar v2 (Vue) | QTable - select at expand rows

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, quasar-framework, quasar

I want to make a table that will have some nesting in the selection of elements. You can see it on the screenshot.

[Table image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf5aM.png)

But the problem is that I did not find how to connect more drop-down lines there. I hope such functionality exists.

CodePen - https://codepen.io/sooqtmrd-the-animator/pen/VwVWVrR

I'm trying to use the following string structure

```
rows: [
        {
          name: 'Договор 1234567890',
          childrens: [
            {
              calories: 159,
              fat: 6.0,
              carbs: 24,
              protein: 4.0,
              sodium: 87,
              calcium: '14%',
              iron: '1%',
            },
            {
              calories: 159,
              fat: 6.0,
              carbs: 24,
              protein: 4.0,
              sodium: 87,
              calcium: '14%',
              iron: '1%',
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Договор 1234',
          childrens: [
            {
              calories: 159,
              fat: 6.0,
              carbs: 24,
              protein: 4.0,
              sodium: 87,
              calcium: '14%',
              iron: '1%',
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use expanding row option quasar table
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#expanding-rows